# Linux / ubuntu usb microphone for singing

Tags: linux, audio, microphone

I have an USB microphone, but I have a problem listening to it on the speakers. It's for singing, karaoke etc.

With `pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1`
or `arecord -f cd - | aplay -` I have strong delay...

There exist some live microphone, live sing software. (live effect will be perfect)

In mix I hear sound, but it often clashes with the loudspeaker. Is it possible to put karaoke from chromium browser and mix it with the sound from the microphone?

In pulseEffects  I can also hear sound, but it have too strong delay.

Another google solution is `sudo apt-get install jackd qjackctl`
but I don't see this device, maybe because it's USB?

With `lsusb` I see

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 31b2:0011 DCMT Technology USB Condenser Microphone
```

(computer is Xeon x12 cores 32 GB RAM, so I think it's enough for real-time - I'm a programmer, so I don't know about karaoke configuration :)